# Prove that the function does not exist....help

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that there does not exist a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the equation $f(x) = c$ has exactly two solutions.

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps start with drawing graphs, develop intuitive reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the intermediate value theorem.

More hints: Consider the (only) two points $x<y\in \mathbb R$ where $f(x)=f(y)=0$. Using the intermediate value theorem, what can you say about the sign of the function in the interval $(x,y)$? And the intervals $(-\infty, x)$ and $(y,\infty )$?

Without loss of generality, make an assumption based on your findings above, and then proceed to entertain the existence of maximum/minimum.

Comment: this is what i came up with:We know that if such a function, f(x), existed then it would then take every value in its range exactly two times. However, this contradicts our definition of a function. So, assume to the contrary that such a function does exist. Then, by using our hypothesis $f(x) = 0$ will be for exactly two values of our x, say a and b. Then we would have, f(a)=f(b)=0 where f would be nonzero everywhere else.
Now, Consider f(x) when a<x<b, x will be either entirely positive or negative because by observation if x were to be positive and negative somewhere between a and b,

Comment: and using the Intermediate Value Theorem, it would have to be zero in between causing us to have yet a third zero of f(x). Which would contradict our hypothesis above.

close?

Comment: so far so good (disregarding the comment "However, this contradicts our definition of a function...", which I do not understand. So now, without loss of generality, assume the sign of $f$ in between $a$ and $b$ is positive. What is the sign in the other two intervals? Does $f$ attain a maximum inside the interval between $a$ and $b$? How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Could such a function, if it existed, have a maximum? Does such a function need to have a maximum?

Comment: Why ask these questions in the answer?

Comment: @Tyma Because answering them leads very directly to a contradiction, essentially similar in flavor to the other answer.